# Moving a SQL Server database to a new server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever I move a SQL Server database to a new server I always to a database backup and restore. I have seen a lot of people, especially DBA's who will to a detach / re-attach of the MDF file instead. What is the preferred method and why? I find a backup/restore to be safer, less likely hood of corruption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did this.  For our small databases, I did a backup/restore - just because I felt like it was 'safer'.   However, when moving LARGE databases, it is so much faster to just detach, copy and attach.  This beats having to do a (usually slow) backup, followed by a copy and a (usually slow) restore.

Microsoft [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187858.aspx) using alter database 'planned relocation procedure'.

Note, you can use attach/detach to upgrade between SQL versions as shown in the link.

Comment: +1 Good answer, this is always a fraught task for non-DBAs who don't do it every day.