# Move SQL Database Files MDF & LDF to New Location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Environment:

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Database not receiving active transactions.

In a production environment I need to move the MDF & LDF files to new drives. Since I have a Window of time to stop active transactions, I thought I could just take a backup of the database and then restore it while configuring the file groups to new location.

I figured this is much better than detaching and reattaching the database with new file name.

Since I am a novice, wanted to check with the experts here. Any suggestion/advise much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving a SQL Server database to a new server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522983/moving-a-sql-server-database-to-a-new-server)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example.  It assumes your database has a single `.mdf` (data) file and a single `.ldf` (log) file.  I will use the `[model]` database as an example.

```
--First, make note of the current location of the db files.
--Copy and paste the physical_names somewhere.  Trust me, if you forget 
--where the files were originally, this will save you some heartache.
SELECT d.name, f.name, f.physical_name
FROM master.sys.master_files f
JOIN master.sys.databases d
    ON d.database_id = f.database_id
WHERE d.name = 'model'  --Replace with the name of your db.

--Now set the new file paths.  
--You can run the ALTER DATABASE statements while the db is online.

--Run once for the mdf/data file.
ALTER DATABASE [model]  --Replace with the name of your db.
MODIFY FILE 
(
    NAME = 'modeldev',  --this is the "logical" file name.
    FILENAME = 'D:\SqlData\model.mdf'  --Replace with the new path\filename.
)

--Run once for the ldf/data file.
ALTER DATABASE [model]  --Replace with the name of your db.
MODIFY FILE 
(
    NAME = 'modellog',
    FILENAME = 'D:\SqlData\modellog.ldf'  --Replace with the new path\filename.
)


--When business rules allow, take the db OFFLINE.
ALTER DATABASE [model]  --Replace with the name of your db.
SET OFFLINE

--Move the physical db files to the new location on disk.

--Bring the db back ONLINE to complete the task.
ALTER DATABASE [model]  --Replace with the name of your db.
SET ONLINE
```

Comment: I prefer this method over a backup/restore when everything occurs on the same SQL Server instance.  There should be less I/O involved.

The detach/reattach method should work just as well, although I think MS says that method will be deprecated...